# The translated text is not replacing the original language in the html files

Tags: python, html, google-translation-api

The code I'm using is

```
    import os
    from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    
    def translate_html_files(root_dir, dest_lang='hi', source_lang='en'):
        # Authenticate the Google Cloud API client
        credentials_file = 'google_translate_key.json'
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials_file
        client = translate.Client()
    
        # Traverse all subdirectories and translate HTML files
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.html'):
                    file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                    print(f'Translating {file_path}...')
    
                    # Open the HTML file and read its contents
                    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                        html_text = f.read()
    
                    # Parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
    
                    # Extract all the text from the HTML
                    text = soup.get_text()
    
                    # Translate the text using Google Translate API
                    translation = client.translate(text, target_language=dest_lang, source_language=source_lang)
    
                    # Replace the original text with the translated text
                    translated_text = translation['translatedText']
                    html_text = html_text.replace(text, translated_text)
                    print(translated_text)
    
                    # Write the translated HTML back to the file
                    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                        f.write(html_text)
    
                    print(f'Translation of {file_path} complete.')
    
        print('All HTML files translated successfully!')
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root_directory = './Websites'
        destination_language = 'ar'
        source_language = 'en'
    
        translate_html_files(root_directory, destination_language, source_language)
```

It should iterate through the folder i specified to find all the html files then translate them, then replace the original text with the translated text, all without touching the styling of files or html elements.

But it does not seem to do what it should, and I don't really know what needs to change here.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `html_text` does not contain _exactly_ `text`, therefore the substitution is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

`get_text()` returns just the text, removing all html tags and such.

So if you took this html:

```
<p>My name is Fred, he <i>whispered</i>.</p>
```

... and ran it through `get_text()`, the result would be:

```
My name is Fred, he whispered.
```

That literal exact string does not exist inside the original html, so calling `.replace()` would not find any matches to be replaced.

Comment: The reason being that it is now a string makes sense. Do you think there is another way to approach this part?